# Create dynamic UiApp questionaire that uses radioButtons

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a questionaire that has dynamic questions in it. The radio options are the same, but the questions will vary. How can I do this properly?

I've used the followimg code but I'm getting a "Error encountered: SimplePanel can only contain one child widget"

```
  var form = app.createFormPanel().setId('form').setEncoding('multipart/form-data');

  var count = 1;

  for (var row in arr) {
    infoLabel = app.createLabel(row).setId('infoLabel');

    var myRadio1 = app.createRadioButton("radio"+count, "Present").setFormValue('P');
    var myRadio2 = app.createRadioButton("radio"+count, "Absent without notice").setFormValue('N');
    var myRadio3 = app.createRadioButton("radio"+count, "Excused Absence").setFormValue('X');
    var myRadio4 = app.createRadioButton("radio"+count, "Late").setFormValue('L');

    //create a form and put the radios in it  
    var formContent = app.createGrid().resize(1,4);
    form.add(formContent);

    formContent.setWidget(0, 0, myRadio1);
    formContent.setWidget(0, 1, myRadio2);
    formContent.setWidget(0, 2, myRadio3);
    formContent.setWidget(0, 3, myRadio4);

    panel.add(infoLabel);
    count++;
  }  

  panel.add(form);
  panel.add(button);

  app.add(panel);
```